# Why can't we play a .MP3 file downloaded from Amazon?

Tags: mp3

My daughter downloaded a .MP3 file from Amazon a few weeks ago.  Now, for some reason, she can't play it in any media player we've got.  I've even tried VLC, and it stops cold.

Why?

Comment: Any error message displayed?

Comment: Is the file complete? It may be corrupt. The same problem affected another user who asked a similar question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the resource is invalid. You can change another one to get downloaded and try again. If it's still can't be played. Then, it'a about the compatibility.

Comment: I think the issue turned out to be about compatibility.